# find and replace string in html files with complex regex

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, awk, command-line

I have thousands of html files in which I need to replace strings. I'm looking for attributes `src` and `href` which starts with `'../'` or `'../../'` or as many time as possible with a host name next.

**Example:**

```
href = "../../../baz.pl/baz.img"

src="../../foo.example.com/baz.img"

href="../bar.pl/style.css"
```

and I need to replace path parts with double slash.

**Example:**

```
../../../baz.pl/baz.img -> //baz.pl/baz.img
```

I need to achieve this in linux bash. What is the best solution? What commands should I use?
I'm currently working with grep to match strings. I know that `find` and `sed` propably would be better solution but I can't merge it together.

Regex that I worked is:

```
(?:href|src){1}\=[\"\']{1}((?:\.\.\/)+)[a-z\.].{1,40}(?:\.com|\.pl){1}
```

As you can see I only need to match `pl` and `com` domains

**UPDATED**

In Netbeans replace tool this regex works:

```
(href|src){1}\=(\"|\'){1}(?:(?:\.\.\/)+)([a-z\.].{1,40}(?:\.com|\.pl)){1}
```

with a replacement:

```
$1=$2//$3
```

Now how to move that to Linux bash?

Comment: Look at the awk command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` with `gensub` to match a group, here `([.]{2}\/)+` :

```
awk -i inplace '{
    print gensub(/(href|src)\s*=\s*\"([.]{2}\/)+(\w)([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)(.com\/|.pl\/)/,
        "\\1=\"//\\3\\4\\5",
        "g");
}' *.html
```

Here in-place file editing is used (`-i inplace`) to update the existing documents

The first part matches `src` or `href` with optional spaces before and after `=` : `(href|src)\s*=\s*\"`

The ending part is matching anything following by `.com/` or `.pl/` : `(href|src)\s*=\s*\"`

Comment: Thank you. Im going to test it right on. Two questions. `(.*)` is it a greedy operator? Will it not consume string unless it meets further domain `.com` or `.pl` in document? How to achieve this in recurse updating all files with its original names?

Comment: I've fixed the issue of `(.*)`with `(\w+)` instead, it takes care of case like ../../foo.example/baz.img.com/a.img. I added `-i inplace` to update the files and match all html files for your target

Comment: this will be it :) i'm just correcting things right now. For instance host name will only have a-z and dot (.) characters. And I'm using + operator instead of *.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5iN64Y/2 i don't understand but `href="../../pl/main.html"` is also matched

Comment: to be specific {n,y} operator does not work i awk. So i got back to `(\.\.\/)+` from `([.]{2}\/)+` and escaped dots in `(\.com\/|\.pl\/)`

Comment: This is strange, the code in post is working fine as is on my computer running awk 4.1.1

Comment: that might be the reason. I'm using 3.0.4